# Back up an external hard drive with video on it

Tags: backup

Can I use Time Machine to back up an external hard drive that I use to store video on to another external hard drive without having to back up the Mac Book Pro as well?

Comment: Yes but complex easier to use another backup tool e.g. CarbonCopyCloner SuperDuper or command line rsync

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can — when setting up Time Machine, add your internal disk to the exclude list and remove your external disk so that it is backed up.